# How to change root location for wslpath?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I am pasting a Windows path into a WSL console window, it gets translated automatically to a WSL path, e.g. `C:\Windows` is pasted as `/mnt/c/Windows`.

However, this does not reflect `root` setting in `/etc/wsl.conf`

For example, I edit `/etc/wsl.conf` and replace line `root = /mnt/` with `root = /` and then run `Restart-Service -Name "LxssManager"` in Powershell and restart WSL.

Now Windows drives are mounted into root directly as `/c/`, `/d/` etc, but pasting `C:\Windows` still results in `/mnt/c/Windows`.
How can I change this so that it pastes `/c/Windows`?

As far as I understand the utility that actually handles the translation is `wslpath` but I can't find how to configure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I am pasting a Windows path into a WSL console window, it gets translated automatically to a WSL path

For clarity, there are two *default* terminals that WSL might use:

- Under Windows 10, the legacy Windows Console Host
- Under Windows 11 (if configured), Windows Terminal

Unless I'm missing something, neither of these does the path translation that you mention.  Windows Console Host is just too old, with no new features other than UTF-8 support in quite a few years.  And Windows Terminal has an outstanding feature request ([#1772](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/1772)) for this.

Based on a comment in that issue, I think it's likely that you are using the [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io) or [cmder](https://cmder.app) (based on ConEmu) terminal.  Windows-to-POSIX path translation is a feature of those terminals.

If that's the case, to change the path prefix that is used, go to *Settings->Tasks* and edit the task you use to start WSL.  Change (or add) the:

```
-cur_console:pm:""
```

The empty string will remove the prefix, so that it will paste as `/c/Windows` instead of `/mnt/c/Windows`.

See [this issue](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/2082) and the referenced [documentation page](https://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html).

Comment: Wow, it somehow didn't occur to me that it could be ConEmu. You are right, that's the one I am using. Although I just run ConEmu and type 'wsl'. There isn't a specific task in its settings for WSL. So, given my usecase, if I launch WSL with `wsl -new_console:pm:""`, I get the desired result. `cur` didn't have an effect though. Thanks!